# Skip Gauge test dynamically

Tags: java, gauge, getgauge

I'm trying to find way to skip Gauge execution dynamically (with ignoring all next steps but without failing).
For example I have some spec

```
Before test
===========================================================
* Before step

Scenario
-----------------------------------------------------------
* Step 1
* Step 2
```

And their implementation

```
@Step("Step 1")
public void step1() {
    if (ignoreCondition) {
        //how to skip test??????
    } else {
        doSomething();
    }
}

//if ignoreCondition==true this step must be ignored
@Step("Step 2")
public void step2() {
    doSomethingElse();
}
```

Is there any way to do like this?

Comment: That sort of thing is not easily accomplished with annotations, and would be one hell of a hack if it did. I highly doubtful any library has that sort of functionality

Comment: No, this is not possible. Please see [this issue](https://github.com/getgauge/gauge/issues/728) for related disucssion